# PigStorage along with FOREACH statement

Tags: apache-pig

While doing FOREACH I need to give a delimiter "`,`"

```
A = FOREACH interdata generate $0,$6 USING PigStorage(',');
```

I tried but showing

```
mismatched input 'using' expecting SEMI_COLON
```

But how can I give delimiter along with FOREACH statement.Is there any other way to do the same
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to store the content of A into a coma separated file and for that you need to use a store statement: STORE alias INTO 'directory' [USING function]. You cannot do it with a foreach statement alone.

**Example**

```
A = FOREACH interdata generate $0,$ 6;
store A into 'output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are trying to give a delimiter here. PigStorage is used with a load statement. So it should be something like.

interdata = load '' using PigStorage(',');

A = foreach interdata generate $0,$6;